# How to remove redundant features using weka

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, feature-selection

I have around 300 features and I want to find the best subset of features by using feature selection techniques in weka. Can someone please tell me what method to use to remove redundant features in weka :)

Comment: are you using weka GUI ?

Comment: Just a random note - the only reason for feature selection is cost of obtaining such features for new objects. If it is not true for your problem you should look for **dimensionality reduction**, not feature selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are mainly two types of feature selection techniques that you can use using Weka:

- Feature selection with wrapper method:

"Wrapper methods consider the selection of a set of features as a search problem, where different combinations are prepared, evaluated and compared to other combinations. A predictive model us used to evaluate a combination of features and assign a score based on model accuracy.

The search process may be methodical such as a best-first search, it may stochastic such as a random hill-climbing algorithm, or it may use heuristics, like forward and backward passes to add and remove features.

An example if a wrapper method is the recursive feature elimination algorithm." [From http://machinelearningmastery.com/an-introduction-to-feature-selection/]

- Feature selection with filter method:

"Filter feature selection methods apply a statistical measure to assign a scoring to each feature. The features are ranked by the score and either selected to be kept or removed from the dataset. The methods are often univariate and consider the feature independently, or with regard to the dependent variable.

Example of some filter methods include the Chi squared test, information gain and correlation coefficient scores." [From http://machinelearningmastery.com/an-introduction-to-feature-selection/]

If you are using Weka GUI, then you can take a look at two of my video casts [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x5wa1w-BpRE) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UOadhDKRbPM).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With your knowledge, can you please sugest me the 'filter' method and 'wrapper' methods that suits well for my problem. (I have around 300 features of 1000 users) Please help me :)